# Область видимости в JS

Tags: javascript

Написать функцию makeRandomFn которая принимает массив чисел и возвращает функцию, которая при вызове возвращает любое число c этого, переданного ей, массива

```js
const getRandomNumber = makeRandomFn([1, 2, 100, 34, 45, 556, 33])

function makeRandomFn() {
  return function getRandomNumber() {
    getRandomNumber[Math.floor(Math.random() * getRandomNumber.length)];
  }
}

console.log(getRandomNumber()) // 556
console.log(getRandomNumber()) // 100
console.log(getRandomNumber()) // 2
```

У меня три undef

Comment: покажи место, где ты что-то возвращаешь из getRandomNumber

Answer (score 3):

По порядку, *написать функцию makeRandomFn которая принимает массив чисел*

```
function makeRandomFn (array){...}  // функция
```

*возвращает функцию, которая при вызове возвращает любое число c этого, переданного ей, массива*

```
return function getRandomNumber () { // тело функции
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
}
```

Посмотреть работу:

```
console.log(makeRandomFn([1, 2, 100, 34, 45, 556, 33])())
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const getRandomNumber = makeRandomFn([1, 2, 100, 34, 45, 556, 33])

function makeRandomFn(array) {
  return () => array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]
}

console.log(getRandomNumber())
console.log(getRandomNumber())
console.log(getRandomNumber())
```

Answer (score 2):

Или по интереснее написать решение вашей задачи.

Задача создать замыкание `getRandomNumber` над массивом чисел которая будет возвращать случайный элемент массива при каждом вызове.

В качестве округления случайного вещественного числа использовать побитовые операции.

```js
const getRandomNumber = makeRandomFn([1, 2, 100, 34, 45, 556, 33])

function makeRandomFn(array) {
  return () => array[(Math.random() * array.length) | 0]
}

console.log(getRandomNumber())
console.log(getRandomNumber())
console.log(getRandomNumber())
```

Ошибка была в возрате замыкания

```
return function getRandomNumber() {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * getRandomNumber.length)];
  }
```

И в объявление параметра в функции

```
function makeRandomFn(array)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111378/discussion-on-answer-by-aziz-umarov----js).